# portable operating system on mac

Tags: live-usb, macbook, macbook-pro, live-environment

I've a Macbook pro 11, 2. I want to use ubuntu as a portable operating system from pen drive. It means that I don't want to install it to disk instead i want to install it on a pen drive and be able to save files / work on it without it restarting from start every time .
Can you point me what I should do ?

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can, it's pretty much just like installing it normally. I took a few moments and found a pretty decent site that will help you out.

http://www.fernhilllinuxproject.com/guidesandhowtos/installubuntutousbdrive.html

They've even taken the time to make a handy video of the process. It's pretty simple, really. Let us know how it goes.